# How to contact a government prosecutor?

Tags: criminal-law

Do public prosecutors work for a city, county, or state, or does it vary by location? Are they called district attorneys, attorneys general, prosecutors, or something else.  Specifically, if I have been a victim of monetary criminal matter, how do I find the prosecutor that has jurisdiction and how can I contact that person?  Is there only one prosecutor that has jurisdiction or do I have a choice among several, such as depending on where I live, where the criminal lives, or where the crime took place?  (I am asking specifically about a matter that involves a wrong-doer in Atlanta and a victim in New York.)  To make initial contact, do I send an email, do I make an appointment, do I just show up at the prosecutor's office?

On reflection, perhaps the crime took place over the internet. I paid by paypal and the other party did not use the money as agreed upon, pocketing it instead. So, where did the crime take place?

Comment: I think in most cases, if you have a crime to report, you would begin by talking to the police, not the prosecutors.

Comment: @NateEldredge  Again the same question applies. Can I approach the local police dept or must I go to Atlanta?

Comment: Usually it is based on where the crime took place. But you could always call your local police and see what they say. Note that you don't have to go to Atlanta to report the crime; a phone call should be perfectly sufficient. (You might at some point need to travel there to testify as a witness; if so, I believe your travel expenses would be paid.)

Comment: @NateEldredge  Well, the crime took place over the internet. It involved paypal.  I paid by paypal and the other party did not use the money as agreed upon, pocketing it instead. So, where did the crime take place?

Comment: I don't know.  But I bet your local police will.  **Ask them.**  (Note that if the "crime" was simply that another party didn't do something they agreed to do, it might not be a crime but a civil matter.)

Comment: @NateEldredge  Misappropriating funds might be criminal. I just do not know.

Comment: @user3270 call your local police non-emergency number.

Comment: Contact paypal customer support and ask them to look into it.

Comment: Alternately, ask a lawyer and see what the lawyer recommends.

Answer (score 4):

You do not contact the District Attorney's Office, the Police do that.  You call your police department and they will dispatch a car to you.  Meet with them and tell them the case.  They will take the report back and get it to the D.A.'s office.  The D.A.'s office will decide if there is a case or not.  If they find there is a case, they will contact you for the next steps.

It starts with a phone call to the police.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a victim in NYC and an accused individual in Atlanta, I would advise ringing the FBI field office in New York as all crimes that cross state lines are automatically Federal Crimes.  The FBI in NYC does have a lot of financial forensics specialists, given that NYC is a major economic center.   Fraud is also typically handled by them by default.

Comment: It would need to be a lot of money before the FBI became interested.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite:  But it is an interstate crime.

Comment: From their web site - FBI priorities - presumably in order of decreasing importance -Protect the United States from terrorist attack
Protect the United States against foreign intelligence operations and espionage
Protect the United States against cyber-based attacks and high-technology crimes
Combat public corruption at all levels
Protect civil rights
Combat transnational/national criminal organizations and enterprises
Combat major white-collar crime
Combat significant violent crime